# disable audio on remote desktop

Tags: windows-server-2008, group-policy, remote-desktop, windows-terminal-services

I am running a Windows 2008 server that has remote users connecting to it via terminal services.

I have group policies in place for each organization that connects.

Is there a way, through group policies, to disable audio on a remote desktop connection?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to disable it for everyone connecting to the system?  Or individual users?

Comment: Everyone within that policy, if possible.

Comment: **You didn't answer my question**.  There is a policy, but it is a **per-computer policy** and it applies to the terminal server, completely disabling audio.  So I guess that is what you want, because it will affect everyone within that policy right?

Comment: Yes that is what I'm wanting

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee791794(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: ty! I'll check it out now.

Comment: That is what I'm looking for! If you post this as your answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The group policy that controls device and resource connection is under.

> Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Device and Resource Redirection.

These settings are per-computer.

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee791794(v=ws.10).aspx for full details.